# Finding count of urls repeating in website crawing using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

How to find the number of URLs repeating in a website? As scrappy framework doesn't scrape duplicate urls by default. I just need to find which URLs are repeating and how many times.

I tried to do it, by calculating the number of URLs repeating at function close spider but after some digging, I realized that we cannot yield anything in this function.

Comment: have you tried using beautifulsoup?

Comment: I need to do it using scrapy only

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source for the `RFPDupeFilter` [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/dupefilters.py#L73), you can see that it keeps record of the number of filtered requests.

If you modify the `log()` method in a subclass, you can get results per url with minimal effort.

Something as simple as this might do the trick, or you might want to further refine it (make sure you set the [`DUPEFILTER_CLASS`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#dupefilter-class) setting):

```
class URLStatsRFPDupeFilter(RFPDupeFilter):
    def log(self, request, spider):
        super().log(request, spider)
        spider.crawler.stats.inc_value(
            'dupefilter/filtered/{}'.format(request.url),
            spider=spider
        )
```

Comment: after  overriding this middleware function , i am able to get duplicate url and their count but i have to yield this response

Comment: What response? The stats are not associated with a response, they are an attribute of the crawler, and as such accessible inside the spider as `self.crawler.stats`

Comment: i want to yield this duplicate url count with reponse of spider(each item with their count avilable on website)

Comment: So you want an item field that will contain the number of times its url was encountered? You can not do that directly from a callback function, since you do not know this count until you've crawled all of the urls. You can do it either using a pipeline which will store the items, and only yield them after the crawl is completed, or as a post-processing step.

Comment: yes,or i can yield all duplicate url with their count just before spider getting closed.

Comment: I guess you can, if you don't want the counts associated with an item...

Comment: I've mentioned some options in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 1):

[This Scrapy Documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) may help you get started. And this code may help you.

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        links_count = {}
        for link in response.css('a').xpath('@href').extract():
            if link in links_count:
                links_count[link] += 1
            else:
                links_count[link] = 1
        yield links_count
```

Run:

```
scrapy runspider yourfilename.py
```

Result:

```
{' https://wordpress.org/': 1, 'https://github.com/scrapinghub': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples/#comments': 1, 'https://www.instagram.com/scrapinghub/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/11/10/how-you-can-use-web-data-to-accelerate-your-startup/#comments': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/07/07/scraping-the-steam-game-store-with-scrapy/': 4, 'https://scrapinghub.com/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/11/05/a-faster-updated-scrapinghub/#comments': 1, 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYb6YWTBfD0EB53shkN_6vA': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/11/05/a-faster-updated-scrapinghub/': 4, 'https://www.facebook.com/ScrapingHub/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/11/10/how-you-can-use-web-data-to-accelerate-your-startup/': 3, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/author/andre-perunicic/': 1, 'http://blog.scrapinghub.com/rss': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/08/25/how-to-crawl-the-web-politely-with-scrapy/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/11/24/how-to-build-your-own-price-monitoring-tool/': 4, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/page/2/': 1, 'https://scrapinghub.com/data-on-demand': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2015/03/02/handling-javascript-in-scrapy-with-splash/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/04/20/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-april-2016-edition/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/author/kmike84/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/author/cchaynessh/': 3, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/11/24/how-to-build-your-own-price-monitoring-tool/#comments': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/about/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/06/22/scrapy-tips-from-the-pros-june-2016/': 1, 'https://www.linkedin.com/company/scrapinghub': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/06/19/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep/#respond': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/author/valdir/': 3, 'https://plus.google.com/+Scrapinghub': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/author/scott/': 2, 'https://scrapinghub.com/data-services/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/': 2, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/04/19/deploy-your-scrapy-spiders-from-github/': 4, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/01/01/looking-back-at-2016/': 3, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/12/31/looking-back-at-2017/#comments': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/12/15/how-to-increase-sales-with-online-reputation-management/#comments': 1, 'https://twitter.com/scrapinghub': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/12/15/how-to-increase-sales-with-online-reputation-management/': 3, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/06/19/do-androids-dream-of-electric-sheep/': 4, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/01/01/looking-back-at-2016/#comments': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2017/12/31/looking-back-at-2017/': 4, 'https://wordpress.org/themes/nisarg/': 1, 'https://blog.scrapinghub.com/2016/10/27/an-introduction-to-xpath-with-examples/': 3}
```